# Conda env yaml use environment variables for secrets

Tags: yaml, environment-variables, conda

I have a project where I have to mix conda dependencies that are publicly available with dependencies from my own private pip package registry. These are all pip dependencies. It is possible to define a pip dependency like this in the env.yml file:

```
name: env-name
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - conda-dependency=1.0.0=s0mel3tters

  - pip:
      - --extra-index-url https://__token_name__:__token__@gitlab.com/path/to/registry
      - pippackage==1.0.0
```

This works. Great. But. I don't want to check my `__token_name__` and `__token__` in source control for obvious reasons. Now it turns out that I can define environment variables into the env.yml that will be created in the actual environment. I want to do something slightly different. I want to read in an environmental variable that already exists and use it in my pip URL definition. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you can substitute for environmental variables:

```
name: env-name
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - conda-dependency=1.0.0=s0mel3tters

  - pip:
      - --extra-index-url https://${TOKEN_NAME}:${TOKEN}@gitlab.com/path/to/registry
      - pippackage==1.0.0
```